# Adding raster Data from Geodatabase to QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, grass-gis, file-geodatabase

I have raster data in a geodatabase and want to open them with QGIS. When I navigate with QGIS to the Geodatabase I get to this window.

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't open These atx and GDBTABLX files and I don't recognize which of layers are the files. In ArcGIS the window just Shows the layer names.

Is there a way to recognize the layer name and open the files in QGIS?